# Why did Nathan trust Kyoko in Ex Machina?

Tags: ex-machina

It looks like Kyoko often is around when Nathan sleeps or is really drunk.

Couldn't she ...

> ... take his key card and free Ava? She wouldn't need to hack the security system and Nathan would be locked in without his key card.

Comment: I think this is too broad a question, as this information is not presented in the film, and there isn't enough evidence for a clear conclusion. We can presume many things. Perhaps he programmed her to be docile, and assumed his programming was airtight. Perhaps he programmed her to serve/assist whoever has his keycard, assuming no one would ever get it away from him. We simply don't know what's been encoded in her artificial brain before the start of the film.

Comment: @recognizer: I used a broad title, so that nothing is spoiled. If there is no explanation in the movie that's a  valid answer. I don't think that the broadness of a question is dependent on the answers.

Comment: I mean that the question is broad not because of the topic itself, but because there are any number of possibilities, each of which would be inferred from only a very small amount of evidence. Any answer you received would essentially be fanfiction.

Comment: She's just a robot, not a sentient AI like Ava.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the view of Nathan, Kyoko has no consciousness or just leaks of intelligence. She is just a tool for sex and serving.

She is more like an animal, following primitive "instincts", like dancing when music and light is set up in the right way, or taking off clothes when being touched in the right way.

Such a "primitive being" cannot figure out a plan like freeing Ava.

Actually, Nathan is surprised that she can even do that thing with the knife.

Comment: I am surprised Nathan would be surprised. He made something that looked human but it seems almost impossible that he could accidentally make it think like human or even like a cat or dog.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Kyoko didn't know Ava exists, and she is programmed just to obey Nathan's requests. But in the end Ava touchs her, speak her and so she is reprogrammed by Ava to kill Nathan. Initially Kyoko is subdued by Nathan, in the end by Ava.

Comment: When Ava touches her, Kyoko already has a knive in hand. But they met twice, once the day before (?), so that Kyoko could have released her that night (killing optional).

Comment: @Chris Ah well, Ava one day before met Kyoko and studied the plane to betray their creator.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [interesting article](https://www.jigocloud.com/en/blog/ex-machina-the-real-ai/) which suggests that Kyoko isn't just a robot programmed with AI like Ava - but is a conscious being that has developed the ability to understand language, has developed human emotions such as empathy and sacrifice.  She learns the difference between right and wrong.

Nathan trusts her because he didn't program her with these emotions or even the ability to speak so doesn't believe she can betray him.  She is the Turing test - because real AI is the ability to learn just like a human child.

Ava is programmed with the desire to escape (well, indirectly - she is programmed with knowledge of the outside world therefore has desire to see it).  Nowhere in the film does Ava show the ability to learn - she always knew how to speak, always knew how to draw, always had the desire to escape.